# C++ How to include source code generated map into application for pre compilation stage

Tags: c++, include

i have application that reads large std::map , that some script generate 
its size  400 - 600 elements
now this std map is generate by script 
some thing like this :

```
expressionsMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(1,"string1"));
expressionsMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(2,"string1"));
expressionsMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(3,"string1"));
expressionsMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(4,"string1"));
...
...
...
...
expressionsMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(5,"string400"));
```

the expressionsMap map is defined in my application header file

```
typedef std::map<int,std::string> ExpressionsMap;
class LevelsManager 
{
private:
   ExpressionsMap expressionsMap; 
}
```

now in the source file i like to include the generated file ( manually ) 
so the definition of the map will be part of the c++ source file .
at list the compiler will see it like this .
im searching for cross platform solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making expressionsMap a pointer, setting it to NULL in the constructor and initializing it on first use (calling a function that contains the #include for the generated code)?

Comment: what i need to include ? just plain *.h" file ? 
with the expressionsMap inside ?

Comment: You just need to include the generated file. So if the generated file containing all the insert statements is called "generated_inserts.h" your function have an include statement like #include "generated_inserts.h"

Comment: Note that you need to change the generated code from using . to -> if you change expressionsMap to a pointer.